# Can I use Expo Packages (such as expo-linear-gradient or expo-mail-composer) Without actually running my app on Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Title sums up the question. I do not want to deal with all of the extra drama that surrounds building a full expo app, but using some of their dependencies might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use Expo APIs in any React Native App](https://blog.expo.dev/you-can-now-use-expo-apis-in-any-react-native-app-7c3a93041331). The same goes for the mentioned packages.

Comment: I get  `Unable to find a specification for `ExpoModulesCore` depended upon by `Expo`` when I use yarn to add the aforementioned dependencies, do I yarn add expo as well?

Comment: You can use the automatic installer by running this command in your project's directory where `package.json` is `npx install-expo-modules@latest`